# Passing Connection String and Timer Interval to Windows Service by GUI

Tags: c#, windows-services, ipc

i want to write a windows service by c# that get data from t1 table in database1 and insert this data into another table in another database (for example t2 in database2). i am using this tutorial series: [Windows Services in C#](http://arcanecode.com/2007/05/21/windows-services-in-c-getting-started-part-1/). briefly, by using a timer , for a period (for example every 1000 ms) data from database1 read and write in database2. this work fine and there are no problem.

i want to provide an GUI for user that he can enter this items:

1. connection string for database 1
2. connection string for database 2
3. interval for timer

because that i am beginning to windows service , i can't do this items. i search in net and SO for this and find that for this problem introduced IPC (Inter Process Communication). but i can't find out IPC and how i can solve my problem by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the real work only every second or so, you could easily read the settings from the registry or a configuration file just before you do your work cycle.

Your GUI application would then be completly independent, it would just write the registry settings or config file, which could be easier than IPC.

If you do want to use IPC, you need to first decide for dome IPC mechanism (I recommend sockets for portability and possible remote configuration, but this is a matter of personal taste), then have your service listen and your GUI app connect and write. Make sure, you don't forget clean authentication.

Comment: thanks, are you can link me to some codes for saving items in registry or config files? or sockets?